# Power control for a smartcard reader

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

Is it possible to control the power to the reader from software?
Both when a smartcard is present in the reader and when the reader is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Depends. I don't think that there is anything in PCSC, so if there is something, it has to be proprietary for the reader (or possibly some generic USB power management API).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard for doing that.

Readers aiming at doing tests, such as the Micropross MP300 or Smartware readers have commands for doing such things.